# Sort a collection on a joined table

Tags: module, magento-1, collection, review

I'm making a module that to order reviews. In de mage-admin I added an extra field which gets saved into a new table `review_featured`
[image: review_featured structure]

On the product page I want to sort it based on the `featured_number`

in *template/review/product/view/list.phtml*
there is the line:  `$_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();`

in `\Mage_Review_Block_Product_View::getReviewsCollection()` I do see filters but how do I add my table to that?

How can I:

1. Join my table `review_featured` when fetching items through the reviews collection?
2. Sort the collection based on the `review_featured.featured_number`?

The module is set up using multiple sources [mainly](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/) and [official](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into `review_review_collection_load_before` and `join()` your table: `\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract::join`

Then you can either `\Varien_Data_Collection_Db::addOrder` or `\Varien_Data_Collection_Db::unshiftOrder`